# Difference between a regular and a stationary source?

Tags: coding-theory, encoding-scheme, entropy, huffman-coding

As far as I understand a stationary source is a regular source but it's not necessarily true the other way around.

And a stationary source is a source for which its distribution is unaffected by a "time shift" ?

Can someone clarify the definition and difference of the two?